# How can I access AWS from a pod running under EKS/KOPS Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kops

I have a pod which I plan to run under EKS & KOPS managed cluster.
The pod does some calculations and I want to write the results to DynamoDB.

How can I access AWS DynamoDB from it?

Also, say I want to package it using helm, is there an option that all of the required configuration to access AWS would be only pod helm package related without any cluster configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need AWS IAM Role mapped to a ServiceAccount. Try using this user guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: yes, but for kops you need to additionally install this webhook to the cluster: https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/. In EKS it's included out of the box

Answer (score 1):

also for kops you can use Kiam project, think of it as an IAM proxy https://github.com/uswitch/kiam